# Drag and Drop IDE for TKX

Tags: perl, user-interface, ide, tkx

Does anyone know of a good IDE for GUIs made with TKX? Drag and drop capabilities like NetBeans or VS would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"SpecTcl is a WYSIWYG GUI-Builder for Tcl/Tk, with sibblings for generating code in Perl, Java, Python & Ruby. It runs on all platforms where Tcl/Tk runs. It is simple and quick to use, yet still powerful when you know your Tcl/Tk."

See http://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/

Comment: Thanks! I asked this more than 2 years ago! Seems to work well. The site doesn't specify this, but the app generates Tkx code (like I asked for). SourceForge also led me to something called Guido, which is alpha and also doesn't specify Tk or Tkx (and I couldn't figure out how to install it).